# Facing base64 pdf encoding issue on google chrome and internet explorer browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, base64

I want to display pdf files on browser. For that I have used following code.

```
<iframe id="sourceimage" scrolling="yes" height="900px" width="730px" style="background: #FFFFFF;" src="data:pdf;base64,<%=documentPreview.attributes.document%>"></iframe>
```

But except mozilla firefox and safari none other browsers are able to display the pdf files.
And funny thing is **on google chrome it automatically gets downloaded** when clicked on a button to see document preview.
I have Google chrome(Version 31.0.1650.63 m) and Internet explorer 11.

What are the issues with these browsers? What is the solution for this? Please help